# pthread_create not enough space

Tags: c, pthreads, mingw, pthreads-win32

I'm using Pthreads with MinGW on Windows. A call to pthread_create returns a error which translates to "Not enough space". What kind of space does it refer to? Is the thread stack space?

```
int scannerThreadReturnValue = pthread_create(&parserThreadHandle, &attr, parserThread, (void *)filename);
    if(scannerThreadReturnValue != 0) {
        printf("Unable to create thread %s\n", strerror(errno));
    }
    else printf("Parser thread creation successfull\n");
```

Comment: check 4th argument passage of `pthread_create()` argument to `parserThread()` must be passed as pointer to struct, are you using attr ?? otherwise set it `NULL`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message most propably is wrong, as the `pthread_*` family of functions does not set `errno`. The error code is returned by the functions.

So mod you code like this:

```
int scannerThreadReturnValue = pthread_create(&parserThreadHandle, &attr, parserThread, (void*)filename);
if (scannerThreadReturnValue != 0)
{
  printf("Unable to create thread: %s\n", strerror(scannerThreadReturnValue));
}
else 
{
  printf("Parser thread creation successful.\n");
}
```

This will give you the correct error message.

Answer (score 0):

This is strange, though am not sure about MinGW, Yes it should be referring to the stack size.  What kind of application is this ?  did you create plenty threads prior to this parserThread ? . In ideal case should not failed in space issue.

Probably you can initiate thread attribute, and try to set stacksize before creating thread. So we can narrow down easily.